# Using the Performance Timing Plugin

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm tyring to implementing the timingPerformance plugin through Adobe DTM. Everything is configured (at least to my knowledge), but there aren't any events triggering.

Here's a snippet of code that's set up within DTM. **Note** that I've removed all the respected plugins so that it Isn't such a big post. But the necessary functions have been added.

When I jump to a secondary page to test the values, I would expect to see the listed events and eVar, but this is not the case. All I see is the eVar that is collecting my previous page name value, but no events.

```
s.pte = 'event110,event111,event112,event113,event114,event115,event116,event117,event118,event119'
//[--------------------------- 1 to 8 ---------------------------][-- 9 --][- 10 -]
s.ptc = false;

/*****Plugin Section*******/   

s.usePlugins = true

function s_doPlugins(s) {

_satellite.notify("doPlugins fired:" + document.readyState);

/* Previous Page Name */
s.prop55 = s.eVar77 = s.getPreviousValue(s.pageName, 's_ppn');

/* Percent Page Viewed */
/* Pre-requisite: Previous Page Name */
var ppv = s.getPercentPageViewed(s.pageName); //get array of data on prev page % viewed
if (ppv && typeof ppv == 'object' && ppv[0] == s.prop55) { //if ppv array returned and prev page id matches prev page name
    s.prop56 = s.eVar78 = ppv[1] + '|' + ppv[2];
}

/* Time Parting Tracking */
var tp = s.getTimeParting('n', '-7');
s.prop44 = s.eVar55 = tp;

/* Performance Timing */
s.eVar77 = s.getPreviousValue(s.pageName, 'gpv_v77', ''); //Record the previous page name in the designated eVar of your choice
//s.performanceTiming('list2') //List variable if one is neededd
/* Pre-requisite: Previous Page Name */

}
```

Am I missing something or not calling something correctly?

Comment: what version of AA code lib are you using?

Comment: also, looks like the most immediate reason is because you have `s.performanceTiming('list')` commented out, so it never runs! (remove the `//` in front of it)

Comment: 2.4.0 - My understanding is the ``s.performanceTiming('list')`` was optional and used for list prop variables. I take it that's not the case?

Comment: No, `s.performanceTiming();` is the trigger that pops the `events`. Specifying "list2" as a parameter to it optionally also populates `list2` with additional info.  The documentation isn't very clear about this.

Comment: Documentation isn't clear at all! I get the trigger, but can you help me understand what would be the purpose of "list" - what's the use case scenario?

Comment: It just pushes load time info for individual resources on the page that you can setup classications for or whatever. Basically if you want to break down the load times and see them at a more granular level, per resource. TBH there are far better (and accurate) tools for measuring site performance like this, so in practice, pushing this to list2 isn't something I usually recommend.  TBH I don't really recommend using this plugin at all since it's not entirely accurate (entirely different tl;dr).  But as a "ballpark", popping the events is "okay"

Comment: I totally agree with you about using it and much rather use the ``getLoadTime`` plugin. And from experiencing this I can understand why you wouldn't use it let alone recommend it. Nonetheless thanks for the help/input on this.

Comment: well the long story short is any javascript solution is inherently limited. Measuring how long something takes to load using something that is itself part of the thing you are measuring is a paradox of sorts. If you really want an accurate answer, you have to measure it with something above the page scope (like at a browser level extension or standalone tool outside of the browser)

Comment: @Brando https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-load-time/fploionmjgeclbkemipmkogoaohcdbig

Comment: @brando was this resolved for you?

Comment: @ZachL - I updated it with an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments the performance timing plugin uses the `s.performanceTiming();` to trigger the actual plugin. With that being said here is how it should be configured in order to properly work.

The `s.pte` is the call for which determines whether or not to execute the actual plugin.

```
`s.pte = 'event10,event11,event12,event13,event14,event15,event16,event17,event18,event19'
//[--------------------------- 1 to 8 ---------------------------][-- 9 --][- 10 -]
s.ptc = false;`
```

Next is to initialize the plugin that is set within the `doPlugins` section of the s_code.

```
/* Performance Timing */
s.eVar9 = s.getPreviousValue(s.pageName,'gpv_v9','');  //Record the previous page name in the designated eVar of your choice
s.performanceTiming('')
```

Note: Adobe Analytics documentation references a "list" option within the `s.perfomaceTiming('list2`)` call itself. This list is optional and is not required; therefore, removing "list" will work for a standard call.